# asp.net connection reset with long running process

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In an asp.net web form, I keep getting a connection reset error message. The page is doing a some long running processing (about 2-5 minutes).

I have no problem when the web request comes from the same machine as the web server. But when the request originates across the network, I get a connection reset error about 1:30 or 2 minutes into waiting for a response.

I have set the  in web.config for this application and put the application it's own application pool.

What else can I try?

### Edit

The purpose of this page is to accept input from the user, calculate something, and send the result back to them. The long running calculation isn't something I can offload until a later time.

Comment: Is the only thing that you are running on the particular site the form itself? Or do you also make other connections to websites from there?

Comment: The site has other webforms. I don't make any new web requests from the server side code.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118261/long-running-code-within-asp-net-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to handle this is to kick of a background thread to process your data, but immediately return an identifier to the browser, normally as a link.  When the link is clicked, the server checks to see if processing is complete - if it is, show the results, if not, display a "please wait" message and the link again, or auto-refresh the page...

Comment: What would the scope of this background thread be? Does it live even if the user quits their browser? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Do not make the browser wait for this long. Make the request asynchronous, make it return right away. If you need to make user wait - do it using Javascript