# Timeout problem with ASP.NET web scraping

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timeout, screen-scraping

I'm trying to implement a web scraping crawler as a part of my ASP.NET MVC project. It works with large data gathered from different URLS using Html Agility Pack. The problem is when I want to actually run the function I get "The connection was reset" from remote server after a minute. I'm getting better result when I run it locally. I have access to remote IIS. Any suggestion to solve this problem and/or any alternatives?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve _all_ of the URLs in one request to your page?

Comment: Yes I guess. there is a loop which generates the URLs and try to capture them. but with this time limit it can just get few of the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a long running process in ASP.NET, it is best to let it run on a different thread.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221/multithreading-in-asp-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845/backgroundworker-thread-in-asp-net) - related questions and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163553.aspx) MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

Connection and network problems could result in such problems. To avoid blocking scraping of other urls you could parallelize the work into separate threads.